# Second Line of Else Block Not Running

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my `else` block, the second line does not appear to be running. It runs `setHelperText` but seems to ignore `setAlertValue`.

```
  const [alertValue, setAlertValue] = useState("error");
  const [errValue, setErrorValue] = useState("Error State");
  const [helperText, setHelperText] = useState('Input "success" to remove error');

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setErrorValue(e.target.value);

    if (e.target.value === "success") {
      setAlertValue(null);
      setHelperText("Update input to re-enable error");
    } else 
      setHelperText('Input "success" to remove error');
      setAlertValue("error"); // this line does not run
  };

  <TextField
       label="Error State"
       message="this is an ERROR message"
       alert={alertValue}
       value={errValue}
       onChange={handleChange}
       helperText={helperText}
   />
```

Comment: You forgot the curly braces `{}` around your `else` block

Comment: for those that don't know, this is a very famous class of bug https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html

Comment: Because you removed the { from else, JS is assuming you just want the next-line (same-line) referenced only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curly braces are missing in your code. It should be like this:

```
if (e.target.value === "success") {
  setAlertValue(null);
  setHelperText("Update input to re-enable error");
} else {
  setHelperText('Input "success" to remove error');
  setAlertValue("error"); 
};
```